# Compare IP in Python

Tags: python, ip

I'm new in Python and still learning.I wanna make an app to compare two IPs , and if not equal, send an Email to me. i wrote this code but I think I have a problem because i haven't received Email. Can anybody help me ?

```
import requests as req
from  ipaddress import ip_interface
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.company.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login('name@company.com', '3ecKSj67JRyNNX5E')

url: str = "https://checkip.amazonaws.com"
request = req.get(url)
ip: str = request.text

ip1 = str(ip)
ip2 = ip_interface('0.0.0.0')

if ip != ip2:
    server.sendmail('name2@company.com','name3@company.com', 'Your IP has been Changed !')
```

I would be so thankful if anybody could help me or suggest better solutions.